# ask assitance for html page tabular layout

Tags: html, css

I ask for a small help with two layouts:

1- In the master page I want the put a logo next to an upper bar.

How can I create such positioning:

a logo aligned to left and close to its right the bar's div.

2- In on specific content page I want to create two divs which split the center equally

and beneath the a wide div.

here is my lame try for the top-bar

http://jsfiddle.net/vYgLL/

Will tabular layout be the easiest?
[image]

Comment: my question is: how bad would it be if I use tabular layout?

Comment: Very bad. Nothing in your layout justifies a tabular layout.