# Twitter bootstrap topbar rtl

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tried to use twiter bootstrap

to create a top nav-bar in my master page.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/ZqCah/1/

I have some bugs and would appreciate some help:

1- I want to turn all my content to be rtl.

meaning `My site` will be the most right and `register` will be the most left.

2- The items are at different hights.

How can I align them to the middle of the bar?

3- I want to add an my site logo to the bar, as seen here

[ask assitance for html page tabular layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088858/ask-assitance-for-html-page-tabular-layout)

can it stick to the screen like the bar itself?

can it share the size with the bar itself?

Comment: Wow, that is not how you should use jsfiddle. Try cleaning up your code to only show the relevant information. And make it work, even minimally...

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545594/twitter-bootstrap-css-that-support-from-rtl-languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create RTL website with twitter bootstrap you can use RTL version of it.

http://pyjamacoder.com/2012/02/01/twitter-bootstrap-v2-rtl-edition/

and

https://github.com/donaldducky/bootstrap-rtl

I create webpage with these

sushiant.com created with rtl version of bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap now (3.3.5) supports RTL! all you have to do is replace all "left" with "right" inside bootstrap.css file (or better, directly on the "less" source files). The carousel maybe needs some tweaking, but 99% of the stuff works fine. Here's an [example](http://itgoldman.com/itay-bs-rtl/bootstrap-3.3.5/less/Theme%20Template%20for%20Bootstrap.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to explore the use of FLOAT and POSITION in your CSS.  Try to separate each of your elements inside DIVs and experiment on FLOAT and POSITION properties.

For example, your number 1 question...you can put "my site" using:

```
<div style="float:left">my site</div>
<div style="float:right">register</div>
```

You can refer to this positioning tutorial http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/