# Twitter Bootstrap CSS that support from RTL languages

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, arabic, right-to-left, persian

I just discover [Twitter Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) and I'm wondering if there is a right-to-left (RTL) version of it.
Does anyone know?

Comment: Not an official one. But it's been forked—use the Google to find one you like.

Comment: For Bootstrap 3, [check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19730598).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would suggest this http://pyjamacoder.com/2012/02/01/twitter-bootstrap-v2-rtl-edition/

Demo: http://donaldducky.github.com/bootstrap-rtl/

Comment: please vote to reopen this question, It's useful for RTL languages, I want to have more editions of RTL version of Twitter Bootstrap.

Comment: So this guy ran the CSS through a conversion tool (R2). Doing so would usually result in code with many unresolved issues. Is he familiar with an RTL language and has he actually tested his output in an actual project with a real RTL language. And what about JS components. Has anyone else tested this and was happy with the result?

Answer (score 14):

I like this: http://rbootstrap.ir/
It works really well.

Answer (score 6):

**For Bootstrap 3**; I recommend [this library](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl). It works on top of Bootstrap core (think of it as a Bootstrap theme) which gives you the advantage of keeping [Bootstrap core](http://getbootstrap.com/) up-to-date without losing the RTL support.

**For Bootstrap 2**; I would suggest [this repository](https://github.com/donaldducky/bootstrap-rtl). It works standalone (not using Bootstrap core as a dependency).

Answer (score 4):

bootstrap 3 arabic RTL ... link: https://github.com/zeroxme/bootstrap-3-arabic

Answer (score 2):

My answer here for:

bootstrap-3-3-7-rtl and RTL Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.6.1

[my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44565587/5881949)

thank you [parsmizban.com](https://parsmizban.com/t/bootstrap-3-3-7-rtl) for creating and share.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty good for bootstrap 3 RTL support. http://www.eyadio.com/post/2013/08/29/Twitter-Boostrap-version-3-with-RTL-support