# RTL support for latest twitter-bootstrap version

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know such support?
I found 2 packages but not for the latest bootstrap version.

Is such package exists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap CSS that support from RTL languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545594/twitter-bootstrap-css-that-support-from-rtl-languages)

Answer (score 1):

You can get yourself right to left,

1. first change all `left` to something like `stackoverflow`
2. Then change `right` to `left`
3. change `stackoverflow` to `right`
4. Now find `margin:` and `padding:` , if like `margin:0 1px 0 5px` change to `margin:0 5px 0 1px`

Java code may need to be changed, I do not know

- replace: ctr+H
- find: ctr+F
- and next find: F3

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this : http://rbootstrap.ir/

It is the RTL version of bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

check this out ..

[Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 RTL support](http://www.eyadio.com/post/2013/08/29/Twitter-Boostrap-version-3-with-RTL-support)

I tested it and it's works so far ..

Answer (score 0):

Both version v3.0.0 & v2.3.2 fully converted to RTL: https://github.com/MohammadYounes/RTL-bootstrap