# configuring bootstrap 3.0 RTL settings

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, right-to-left

I developed ASP application with Bootstrap 3.0. I need to change the bootstrap from LTR to RTL.

What will be the easiest / fastest way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap CSS that support from RTL languages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545594/twitter-bootstrap-css-that-support-from-rtl-languages)